# top two elements of an associative array in php

Tags: php, associative-array

I've accomplished the end goal for this already, but maybe there is a more elegant way of accomplishing this.

If I have an array like such:

```
$data = array(
    'wood' => 2,
    'metal' => 5,
    'plastic' => 3, 
);
```

I want to get the top 2 key/value pairs from $data (ie metal:5 & plastic:3). Here's what I came up with:

```
arsort($data);       //put values in order
reset($data);           //set pointer to first element
$first = each($data);    //assign first element to $first
array_shift($data); //remove first element from array
reset($data);           //set pointer to the new first element
$second = each($data); //assign the new first element to $second
```

Comment: Array shift resets by default. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php

Comment: Do you really want the key/value pair?  Or just the value?  Because the code you say accomplishes your goal does not get the key...

Comment: @Johan, yeah it does - $first[0] returns "metal"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For getting both key and value I would go this way:

```
arsort($data);
$result = array_slice($data,0,2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
asort($data);
$first = array_pop($data);
$second = array_pop($data);
```

Notice that instead of putting it in reverse order and grabbing the first items, I put it in order and grabbed the last items.

Comment: Agree with this one.  Could just as easily stick with arsort() and use array_shift() instead though.

Comment: @simshaun: Yes... it just makes more sense (to me) to grab the last two items _in_ order than the first two items _out of_ order.

Comment: Just be aware, that it actually removes elements from the array. Also, you're not getting a key, which seems to be what OP wants.

Comment: @Mchl: Yes, excellent point.  But then, so does the OP's code; he apparently doesn't care.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, you just have some extra calls there

```
arsort($data);
$first = each($data);
$second = each($data);
```

should be enough.

You need to be more specific though about what exactly you want to get. `each` returns an array of *four* elements - is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$array = array (
    'wood'  => 2,
    'metal' => 1,
    'blah'  => 4
);

$first  = end($array);
$second = prev($array);
```

Comment: That would not work unless the array was already sorted in ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not exactly what a [Priority Queue](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Priority_queue) was intended for and [regular array sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445077/top-two-elements-of-an-associative-array-in-php/4445191#4445191) and [extracting functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445077/top-two-elements-of-an-associative-array-in-php/4445118#4445118) are completely fine either, but to add something new:

```
$queue = new SplPriorityQueue;
$queue->setExtractFlags(SplPriorityQueue::EXTR_BOTH);
$queue->insert('wood', 2);
$queue->insert('metal', 5);
$queue->insert('plastic', 3);
```

This is automatically sorted in descending order of the numeric value. To get the elements, do

```
var_dump(
    $queue->extract(),
    $queue->extract()
);
```

would give ([codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/7ZJRfW))

```
array(2) {  ["data"]=>  string(5) "metal",    ["priority"]=>  int(5) }
array(2) {  ["data"]=>  string(7) "plastic",  ["priority"]=>  int(3) }
```

and leaves `$queue` containing only 'wood' then.

In addition to the [`SplPriorityQueue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splpriorityqueue.php), you could also use an [`SplMaxHeap`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splmaxheap.php).

Read more at:

- [Matthew Turland's Blog: New SPL Features in PHP 5.3](http://matthewturland.com/2010/05/20/new-spl-features-in-php-5-3/) and
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957133/php-spl-reference-documentation/4218646#4218646